# How to add a delete function to angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, api, crud

I've been working on angular that links to my back end API. I can retrieve my list of businesses from the back end and post reviews etc. But i am having trouble deleting records. I call the delete function in my by back end and nothing happens. Here is my code for reference:

web.service.ts:

```
public deleteBusiness(id: any){
    **return this.http.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/businesses/' + this.id);**
```

business.component.ts

```
deleteBusiness(){
  **this.webService.deleteBusiness(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(**
    (resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
    },
    (err) => console.log(err)
  );
```

and the html button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click) ="deleteBusiness"> Delete</button>
```

i feel like it might be something to do with the 2 lines of code i've marked with '**'for reference. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: call `deleteBusiness` in a template: `(click) ="deleteBusiness()"`

Comment: Good point!  Are you actually hitting your deleteBusiness() method?  If so, then I'd set a breakpoint in your server code and see if that gets hit.  If not, you're route could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you add event listeners in a template like this `(eventName)="$handler"` you need to remember that `$hanler` in this case is not callback binding. It's code that will be passed INSIDE of the callback. You can write logic to this place, for example: `(click)="callFunction(); $event.preventDefault();"`

Everything looks fine with functions, the functions are just not called.

Comment: Ah yes i understand better now, so what do i have to add in order to call the function? I thought i had called it correctly. Is it an issue with the (this.http.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/businesses/' + this.id) or am i calling it wrong between the deleteBusiness in business.component.ts

Comment: replace `(click) ="deleteBusiness"` with `(click) ="deleteBusiness()"` in template.